# What is the aerial equivalent of bathing when one enjoys the breeze?

Tags: single-word-requests, poetic

To wash by immersing one's body in water is called bathing. Then what is the verb for lounging in a breeze enjoying the wind washing through your hair, your underarms and your toes?

I'm trying to translate this phrase. I would like a verb for air bathing that is equally poetic and languorous.

“浴乎沂，风乎舞雩，咏而归"

A direct, unpoetic translation might be:

> To (water) bathe in the Yi river, to (air) bathe by the Wuyu altar, to sing back home.

Comment: ......Chilling?

Comment: close. one can chill in his room as well as in the wind. need a word dedicated to wind only.

Comment: You can bathe or bask in air.

Comment: basking is sun bathing. the word I'm looking for is wind bathing.

Comment: This sort of thing is loaded with metaphor, so you're very unlikely to find a word that specifically only refers to air.

Comment: lounge if sitting, else loll. Not sure there's a word dedicated to this specific action, though.

Comment: You can hang in the breeze, but it probably has connotations that you won't want.

Comment: Please provide the context for how this will be used, so that we can understand why basking and bathing are not appropriate words.

Comment: Basking is not just sun bathing.  There's another definition related to enjoying something such as "basking in the love of your friends and family."  Because of that, I like "basking in the gentle breezes of the Gulf shore." for example.

Comment: See the proverb I provided. It says "to bathe in this river, chill in that altar's wind and sing back home." It's the ideal pleasure and ambition of a the Chinese gentry class.

Comment: I think chill should work.

Comment: **windbathing** can be used actually. It is a therapy term mainly.

Comment: For some reason, Google Translate suggested “dance” for the middle part of the phrase. “Dance in the wind” is actually a reasonably poetic thing to say, although I don't know whether it captures the sentiment of the phrase.

Comment: *Bathing* would probably be the best word, except that you probably want a contrast from *bathing in the river* to make the translation work. *Basking, relaxing, chilling,* and *dancing* are all potentially good words, depending on the exact shade of meaning you want.

Comment: @Bradd, that’s because 舞雩 _Wǔyú_ literally means ‘dance rain-praying-ceremony’. In this case, though, it is a proper noun, the name of a specific altar in the Lu State in Ancient China, where this ‘raindance’ was performed. (Similarly, 沂 _Yí_ is the name of the river in which the gentry swam.)

Comment: If I translate one to one, it's like this: to bathe in Yi(name of a river) and to wind in Wuyu(name of a temple platform). Wind is used as verb. google made a mistake by translating the name of the alter into dance.

Comment: Notice the underlying laziness in this gentleman's ambition. Preferably, the translation should have as little movement as possible.

Comment: *Basking* is an excellent word for relaxing, but it does suggest warmth, so *cooling* might work better for you. I wouldn’t actually recommend *chilling*; see my answer.

Comment: By the way, translation and writing advice are usually off-topic here, but you have probably given enough clues to provide decent suggestions.

Comment: I've incorporated some of your feedback in comments into the question. Please check that it accurately reflects what you're asking. I described your “little movement as possible” as *languorous.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bathing* would ordinarily be a good translation, and poetic because of alliteration with *balmy breeze,* but you probably want a different verb since you’re using *bathe* to contrast with the first part of the translation.

*Basking* is another good word for bathing in the air, and it’s also alliterative, but it has connotations of warmth that you may not want in this specific context.

*Cooling* directly expresses the sensation of relaxing in a breeze. *Chilling* is also possible, but literally it would imply some discomfort; there’s a slang meaning of “relaxing,” but it’s probably the wrong register for poetry.

Comment: Chill should work. Or a one or two syllable word for windbathing.

Comment: My instincts in Mandarin are not quite sharp enough to know whether 风 _fēng_ ‘wind’ to someone who grew up knowing this expression in his native language implies a _cool_ breeze or a _balmy_ one. ‘Cooling’ is fine if it’s a cool breeze, but ‘cooling in the balmy breeze’ sounds a bit odd. Another option might be to simply let the objects themselves make the contrast: **Bathe in the waters of the River Yi and the breeze/winds of the Wuyu Altar, and then return home singing**.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Janus’s translation sounds good. I would recommend *basking* or *cooling* depending on whether the wind is warm or cool. A *chill* is uncomfortable, not balmy, so I would avoid that word.

Comment: @GeorgeChen *Chill* does have a slang meaning of “relax,” but it’s not “poetic.”

Comment: @Janus, you know exactly what I'm trying do--to use wind as a verb.

Comment: @Janus, I am very impressed. It's ancient Chinese, very foreign to me too.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Actually, *cooling* has some good colloquial connotations for this context too (as in “cooling your heels,”) so I think I would recommend that one above the rest. But honestly, Janus’s translation is better than mine.

Comment: OK. I settle for cool off. Bathe in the waters of Yi and cool off in the breeze of Wuyu, then return home singing.

Comment: @GeorgeChen You don’t need to write *cool off* – just *cool* is good.

Comment: Cool. Roger that.

Comment: @Janus, Trust me. You know way more classic Chinese than I do.

Comment: @Janus, you are right. Literally, there is no implication of cool or balmy. It definitely implies something enjoyable, like enjoying the wind, as opposed to braving the wind. That is why I use balmy breeze.

Answer (score 3):

To bathe (or soak) in the Yi river, to enjoy the caress of breezes at the Wuyu altar, to return home reciting poetry.

Comment: I like it as a whole.

Comment: Seems that there is not such activity in the English world. Lounging in the wind doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider a term you already used - **[wash](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wash)**

> to pour, sweep, or flow in a stream or current: *waves of pioneers washing westward*

The term is often used to indicate a flow of almost anything. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breeze%20washed,%20air%20washed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,breeze%20washed;,c0;.t1;,air%20washed;,c0) shows usages for *breezed washed* and *air washed*.

Perhaps

> To bathe in the Yi river, to *wash in the breezes* by the Wuyu altar, to sing back home.

Comment: It is true pilots use words like "down wash" to explain how the wing works. But the immediate mental image wash invokes has something to do with water.

Answer (score 1):

How about to *indulge* in the breezes?

> To bathe in the streams of River Yi, indulge in the breezes by the
>   Wuyu altar, and return home in carefree song.

In my opinion that conveys the "underlying laziness in this gentleman's ambition" quite well.

Comment: In this case, lounging is more concrete. Indulge is too abstract by comparison.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Perhaps, but poetry doesn't necessarily have to be concrete, does it? :) It's always up for personal interpretation, as is the case with your interpretation of this phrase in 古文.

Comment: Poetic words invoke vivid mental images, which is the opposite of abstract.

Comment: No interpretation. I need a word that causes spontaneous effects.

Comment: Literally it means wind bathing, right? No body wind bathes in a wind that is not a balmy breeze.

Comment: So my interpretation of the Chinese is within limits.

Comment: Bear in mind that I never meant to criticize your interpretation. Rather, I am stating that your interpretation is still *yours*, and may differ from others'.

Comment: Literary Chinese leaves too much for imagination. That is a fact.